# Subset a data frame by datetime (POSIXlt) values using datetime (POSIXtl) values from another dataframe in R

Tags: r, datetime

The first df contains the values of temperature measurements made every 30 minutes for 2 months by sensors in different locations. Looks something like this:

```
     date_time            id        Temp
2012-02-27 00:11:00   |  Sens_1  |  23.0
2012-02-27 00:11:30   |  Sens_1  |  23.4
2012-02-27 00:12:00   |  Sens_1  |  24.6
2012-02-27 00:12:30   |  Sens_1  |  25.2
2012-02-27 00:13:00   |  Sens_1  |  25.5
2012-02-27 00:13:30   |  Sens_1  |  26.3
           :               :          :
2012-02-27 00:11:00   |  Sens_2  |  34.6
2012-02-27 00:11:30   |  Sens_2  |  33.4
2012-02-27 00:12:00   |  Sens_2  |  34.6
2012-02-27 00:12:30   |  Sens_2  |  35.4
2012-02-27 00:13:00   |  Sens_2  |  36.5
2012-02-27 00:13:30   |  Sens_2  |  38.8
          :                 :         :
2012-02-27 00:11:00   |  Sens_3  |  14.6
2012-02-27 00:11:30   |  Sens_3  |  14.4
2012-02-27 00:12:00   |  Sens_3  |  13.6
2012-02-27 00:12:30   |  Sens_3  |  15.4
2012-02-27 00:13:00   |  Sens_3  |  15.5
2012-02-27 00:13:30   |  Sens_3  |  16.8
          :                 :         :
```

The second df has just one column with the datetime values that have been filtered previously due to other constrains and so have just part of the datetime values. For example:

```
date_time         
2012-02-27 00:11:00
2012-02-27 00:12:00
2012-02-27 00:12:30
2012-02-27 00:13:30
           :
```

What I want to get is something like this:

```
  date_time            id        Temp
2012-02-27 00:11:00   |  Sens_1  |  23.0
2012-02-27 00:12:00   |  Sens_1  |  24.6
2012-02-27 00:12:30   |  Sens_1  |  25.2
2012-02-27 00:13:30   |  Sens_1  |  26.3
           :               :          :
2012-02-27 00:11:00   |  Sens_2  |  34.6
2012-02-27 00:12:00   |  Sens_2  |  34.6
2012-02-27 00:12:30   |  Sens_2  |  35.4
2012-02-27 00:13:30   |  Sens_2  |  38.8
          :                 :         :
2012-02-27 00:11:00   |  Sens_3  |  14.6
2012-02-27 00:12:00   |  Sens_3  |  13.6
2012-02-27 00:12:30   |  Sens_3  |  15.4
2012-02-27 00:13:30   |  Sens_3  |  16.8
          :                 :         :
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `merge(df1, df2)`

Comment: `do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df1,df1$id), function(x) x[x$date_time %in% df2$date_time,]))`

Comment: Thanks for your quick answers
d.b answer works well
@Gregor: 'merge' didn't work and throws this error: 
Error in sort.list(bx[m$xi]) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
It's suppose to happen when the data it isn't a data.frame but a list instead. I tried 'str' in both df and says this:
'str(sens)
'data.frame': 3342 obs. of  3 var
$ id       : chr  "Sens_1" ..
$ fechahora: POSIXlt, format: "2014-01-01 00:00:00"  ..
$ valor    : num  22.3  ..'

Comment: Well the first `str` you post looks good. The problem must be the second one.

Comment: I didn't realize the second one is missing. I probably erased it when editing.

Here it is:

str(fechas_val)
'data.frame': 2436 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ fechahora: POSIXlt, format: "2014-01-01 11:30:00" "2014-01-01 11:45:00" ...

Answer (score 2):

One way to do that is a right-join. You can use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% right_join(df2)
```

Here's some [useful documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/two-table.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I got an error.

Joining by: "datetime"
Error: cannot join on columns 'datetime' x 'datetime': Can't join on 'datetime' x 'datetime' because of incompatible types (POSIXlt, POSIXt / POSIXlt, POSIXt)

Comment: That error suggests your two date_time columns are not of the same type. If they were, the join would work. Also for join to work, `date_time` should be stored as POSIXct in both data frames.